Why does my Python sort function return None instead of the sorted list?
I am working on a Python project where I need to sort a list of integers. I wrote a custom function to sort the list, but instead of returning the sorted list, it returns None. Here is the function I wrote:
Code:
def sort_list(input_list):
    input_list.sort()

print(sort_list([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]))

I expected this function to print the sorted list [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 9], but it prints None. I suspect the issue is related to how I'm using the sort() method or how I'm returning the result.
Could someone help me understand what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Your function doesn't have a return statement in it.

Your calling of the sort() method is fine, its just that you should return that list using return input_list.

It's a convention to emphasize that the argument is modified in-place, rather than returning a new value and leaving the argument unmodified.

It just sort original list without return. You may return input_list if you want

use return to be able to return data
def sort_list(input_list):
    input_list.sort()
    return input_list

print(sort_list([3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]))


In How to Answer, note the section Answer Well-Asked Questions and the bullet point regarding questions that have been "asked and answered many times before".
